# Use an array to target specific element(s) in a repeated class in jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamically generated HTML portion on a page with numerous repaeted elements with the class of `<div class="paraContent">`

I have access to the `<head>` of this page in the CMS, and want to specify the elements in an array or script to hide certain ones.

My code so far:

```
var excContent = ['0', '1', '25']

$(".paraContent").each(function(index[excContent]) {
    $(this).hide();
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, that is hiding some of the elements having class `paraContent` based on their index, you could do

```
$.each(excContent, function(){$('.paraContent:eq('+this+')').hide()});
```

or (faster if you have a big array) :

```
var $all = $('.paraContent');
$.each(excContent, function(){$all.eq(this).hide()});
```

Comment: @ dystroy That's great. Thank you so much! (@Shadow Wizard: Ta for the fiddle!)

Answer (score 1):

While [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13249420/447356) is correct and pretty much ideal I will go ahead and give alternate way which is still pretty efficient and will iterate all the elements, thus allowing you to do things for elements not in your array of items to hide:

```
var excContent = {'1': true, '0': true};
$(".paraContent").each(function(index) {
    if (excContent[index.toString()])
        $(this).hide();
})
```

​As you can see, the trick is using associative array instead of plain array, then searching it becomes a trivial action.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/8veeE/2/).